# Density plots in R: differences with and without $

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot, facet-grid, dollar-sign

I have a dataframe `d` like this

```
head(d) 
       Id Group    Index
1 ID_key1     F 38.69361
2 ID_key2     A 34.01609
3 ID_key3     A 31.21704
4 ID_key4     A 30.72222
5 ID_key5     F 39.52463
6 ID_key6     A 28.98853
```

and I want to plot a **density plot** of the variable **Index**  grouping observations by the variable **Group**

I did it using the following code

```
ggplot(d, aes(x= Index)) + geom_density() + facet_grid(Group~ .)
```

and I obtained this density plot

[image: density plot]

However, I noticed that if I use the dollar `$` to select the data for the plot within the previous line of code, like this

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = d$Index)) + geom_density() + facet_grid(d$Group~ .)
```

the resulting graph is totally different:

[image: the resulting graph]

I always thought that the two forms were equivalent. Why there is this difference between the two plots?